# Android Studio click and movement monitoring

Tags: android

Is there a way to track extremely general data like number of clicks (touches) on an Android phone? 
Or for instance distance "traveled" by scrolling the screen up and down? 
Keylogging texts in every native app like sms and chrome?
Tracking data usage?
All of this with my app running in the background.
I would like to collect some of this information for my app to use.
Thank you :)

Comment: Fortunately, this is not generally possible, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: but there are definitely apps that track data usage for instance.

Comment: The number of bytes transmitted by an app is less of a privacy and security issue than what the user typed into the app.

Comment: I see. What about scrolling? It is easily tracked on a pc along with clicks.

Comment: Touch events, like key events, are not generally recordable, for obvious privacy and security reasons. The OS has no concept of "scrolling" -- that is how an app interprets touch events in a particular portion of its UI. The only piece of what you're asking for that is supported (somewhat) is tracking data usage -- see `TrafficStats` (and I apologize for having missed that in my original comment).